# Why are my Sass variables shown as not defined upon compilation?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to set up a project with Sass, and even though I have already made multiple Sass projects and everything seemed to work just fine, now I'm not able to use Sass (SCSS) variables at all. I checked and re-checked all of the syntax multiple times, however I can't seem to find the solution. I use dart-sass, but in the SCSS formatting.
My file structure:

- styles

  - css

    - style.css
    - style.css.map
  - scss

    - components

      - _components.scss (uses `@forward` to import the rest of the files)
    - globals

      - _globals.scss (uses `@forward` to import the rest of the files)
      - basics.scss
      - colors.scss (the color variables that I'm talking about are declared here)
      - fonts.scss
      - typography.scss
    - util

      - _util.scss (uses `@forward` to import the rest of the files)
      - functions.scss
    - style.scss (uses `@use` to import the rest of the partial indexes)
      My syntax for declaring variables and then calling them should be alright:
      Declaring (in `colors.scss`):

  `$blue-300: hsl(204, 100%, 45%);`
  Then calling them (e.g. in `_globals.scss`):
  `h1 {color: $blue-300;}`

I suspect it has something to do with the scope of the documents and their locations in individual folders, but I still can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By defaut @use and @forward namespace their variables (see [this](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace)). Try `@forward *file* as *` and `@use globals/globals as *`. This will remove the namespace. If you do want the namespace, try `globals.colors.$blue-300`.

also can you tell the version of sass you're using? (`sass --version`)

Comment: I use sass 1.43.5. I tried using the markup you suggested, but I can only use it with `@use` in the global style.scss. When I tried using it with `@forward`, I got an error saying `Expected identifier` in the place where `as *` was typed.

Comment: Then you can try removing `as *` and replace `$blue-300` with `colors.$blue-300`. I don't see any other way (except `globals.colors.$blue-300`)

Comment: Didn't work either...but thanks for tips